# Downloading feature class from ArcGIS Online web map?

Tags: editing, arcgis-online, download

I'm new to ArcGIS Online (or ArcGIS.com as they're calling it now), and I'm confused as to how data is organized, and how it is accessible. I created a new map, chose Add -> Create Editable Layer, and set up an editable layer open to the public for people to submit input. Now I want to download this feature class to my computer. The only option I know of is to go to "My Content" then download the entire web map as a map package, but when I open it up, it only has the basemap and not the editable layer.

**Is it possible to download this data as an individual feature class (shapefile), or at all?**

Comment: The menu path you note, *"Add >> Create Editable Layer"* does not exist for me  with the Arcgis.com Map Viewer. All I get are options to add a layer from web, shapefile, csv. I do have *"Add Features >> More >> Create Layer >> (select from template)"* in Online Explorer, and when I do that and save the answer provided by @artwork21 works.

Answer (score 6):

You can download edit layers from arcgis.com:

1. Under your Content page click on the ... (three dots) next to the Feature layer you want to download and select the View item details option.
2. Under the Layers section click on the Export To drop down and select whatever export format you want to export to (Shapefile, CSV, KML, FGDB...etc).

Comment: I just tried this again, and like I mentioned above, all that is in the .pkinfo file is an mxd with the basemap layer. There is no layer for the editable feature class, and there isn't even a gdb within the "Your Map Name" file path you mention - just the mxd. (that was a good idea though)

Comment: Could you elaborate on where to find the Open button please? The only way I found was to "Open in Desktop" in the "..." drop down list that appears in the . No download option tho. If I click on the map, it will only give me the options to Open in ArcGIS desktop instead of download.

Comment: @AndrewLebron, this q/a is old and AGOL has changed much since then.  I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 5):

This probably won't work for many features but sometimes this can get the data you need:

https://developers.arcgis.com/labs/arcgisonline/query-a-feature-layer/

For example:
`https://services3.arcgis.com/GVgbJbqm8hXASVYi/arcgis/rest/services/Trailheads/FeatureServer/0/query?where=1=1&outFields=*&returnGeometry=true`
returns a GeoJSON version of the layer of the feature service.

[image: find the URL to the service itself for your layers here]

Find the URL to the service itself for your layers as shown above.

The first parameter, in this case `/0/` controls the layer, first, second third, etc.

I used `&where=1=1` to query for all the features.

The metadata for projection which ESRI provided wasn't accepted by mapshaper even though it was standard webmercator, so I had to specify it manually (it shows it at the top of the GeoJSON and you can check for the corresponding proj.4 string on e.g. https://epsg.io/3857):

`mapshaper -i arcgis-output.geojson -proj +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs from='+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs' -o arcgis-output-prj.geojson`

Comment: Just to clarify a few things: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mapshaper is a geospatial converter tool from a New York Times data team member. Install with `npm install -g mapshaper` once you have NodeJS installed. You can ask for it to output your downloaded ESRI layer as a shapefile from the GeoJSON if you like, just put `-o arcgis-output-prj.shp` instead of `-o arcgis-output-prj.geojson`.

Comment: I think need to add `f=pgeojson` on the URL for the geojson format

Comment: If pgeojson is not available this ObserveableHQ-based converter from proprietary ESRI json may be handy: https://observablehq.com/@thadk/arcgis-json-parser-to-geojson . It will do the work of constructing a query link like the one above. The main caveat is sometimes with large data, the server can still time out and not provide anything.

Answer (score 3):

I found this solution to download data from [ArcGIS Online Help](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/use-maps/extract-data.htm):

It basically says that you can export a CSV or Shapefile or KML from a layer

- if it's a hosted feature service on ArcGIS Online
- and you own the features
- and you are either an administrator for your ArcGIS Online organization
- or the service owner allowed you to export the data.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to previous answers, you can also download shapefiles of your map data in ArcGIS.com if you have ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap installed on your computer.

If that's the case,
You can open ArcMap -> click "file" -> "Sign in ArcGIS Online" -> put your login info -> click "file" -> "ArcGIS online" -> then you will see a pop-up window with your maps from ArcGIS Online -> click "add" on the ones you want to download.