# Downloading features from website with interactive map as shapefiles?

Tags: shapefile, arcgis-online

I found an interactive map on a website: [here](http://www.acwr.com/economic-development/rail-maps/canadian-national)

The map on the website looks like this:

[image]

Is there any way to do download the red lines as shapefiles?

Comment: Check this post: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54374/how-can-i-download-a-feature-class-from-an-arcgis-online-web-map

Comment: Is this the same features?: https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=fb3839823b5042359a3624830d513be3 It is possible to download as shapefiles

Comment: @fabio.avigo I am not using ArcGIS online. I am using a different website.

Comment: @BERA I don't want the entire railway map of canada, but only specific railroad companies.

Comment: @pnkjmndhl the map sure look like an ArcGIS online map

Comment: @pnkjmndhl Well, but since you already have the possibility of downloading the entire railway map, isn't it simpler to filter it?

Comment: You could open the [feature service from here](https://angp.maps.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=c89a8b2ea94241a7875f7a469feba66a) in ArcMap and export to a shapefile. However it appears this is 1 single polyline with no attributes. I'm sure you could find better data elsewhere of a rail network as mentioned previously.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the layer ( arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=c89a8b2ea94241a7875f7a469feba66a) into ArcMap and export it as a FC or SHP.

Comment: What if the map is not available on ArcGIS online?

Comment: You can try to use data extraction tool in ArcMap.

Answer (score 0):

It is available in JSON the direct link is 
it is in json format:

[Direct link to JSON](http://services.arcgis.com/WwCp9CWUBJDXJO79/arcgis/rest/services/CN/FeatureServer/0/query?f=json&where=1%3D1&returnGeometry=true&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&maxAllowableOffset=1.0583354500042337&outFields=*&outSR=102100&resultOffset=0&resultRecordCount=1000&quantizationParameters=%7B%22mode%22%3A%22view%22%2C%22originPosition%22%3A%22upperLeft%22%2C%22tolerance%22%3A1.0583354500042337%2C%22extent%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22extent%22%2C%22xmin%22%3A-130.340134%2C%22ymin%22%3A29.9020106363637%2C%22xmax%22%3A-63.27264%2C%22ymax%22%3A60.845501%2C%22spatialReference%22%3A%7B%22wkid%22%3A4326%2C%22latestWkid%22%3A4326%7D%7D%7D)

This can be converted using ETL Tools to shapefiles.

*(The link was too long for a comment so posted this as an answer.)*

Comment: Error: Server not found

Comment: please try again...